# SwiftLint Change Rules Cocoapods

Tags: swift, cocoapods, swiftlint

I just recently installed SwiftLint using CocoaPods. I want to change the rules of my SwiftLint but when I go inside my pods -> SwiftLint, I cannot find the file named "rules" through which I can edit my rules. Please let me know how I can do the same! Thanks a lot! I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You put rules unique to your project in a file called `.swiftlint.yml` (with the leading `.`) and commit this to source control. Re this file, see the [Configuration](https://github.com/realm/SwiftLint/blob/master/README.md#configuration) section of the README.

If you haven’t done this before, you’ll have to create this file. Personally, I fire up Terminal, `cd` into the root directory of my project, and type `touch .swiftlint.yml` to create a blank file. Then go to your text editor of choice and add whatever rules you want (see the README for some examples, perhaps copy-and-paste some examples into your file).

If you go to YouTube, search for “swiftlint” and you’ll see many tutorials out there.

Comment: Hey Rob, where will I be able to find this file?

Comment: How can I do that? Sorry I haven't worked with SwiftLint before, and my knowledge of terminal is less...

Comment: Its kinda hard to understand what they are telling in the GitHub project... How can I create this and where should I do so?

Comment: Hey thanks Rob, so when I create that file, do I need to copy paste the rules that I want to apply?

Comment: I just directly copy pasted the code in the GitHub repository to the file that I created and I get the following error :

Comment: Loading configuration from '.swiftlint.yml'
Linting Swift files at paths 
No lintable files found at paths: ''
Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code

Comment: I fixed it!! Thank you so much I really appreciate it!

Comment: .Hey Rob, how can I change the maximum line length? In the .swiftlint.yml file, I have changed the `line_length: 200` though In the App Delegate, it shows me this : Line Length Violation: Line should be 120 characters or less: currently 145 characters (line_length)

Comment: Maybe the `.swiftlint.yml` is in the wrong directory and it’s not finding it. I can’t say. Make sure it’s in the same top level directory that your MyApp and MyApp.xcodeproj directories are located. But SwiftLint handles the `line_length` rule fine. When you run it, do you see the “Loading configuration from '.swiftlint.yml’” message (confirming that it found and used the `.yml` file)? It should appear right before the “Linting Swift files at paths” message.